# rename batch of file remove anything in the parenthesis

Tags: java, bash

I want to remove the file and remove anything in the parenthesis

---

Now I have file:

123-456(434).jpg

454-6hf(32).jpg

99-ggr4(44335).jpg

---

rename to:

123-456.jpg

454-6hf.jpg

99-ggr4.jpg

Comment: You need to be more clear on your question, do you have any code to show? Are you using any libraries? etc.

Answer (score 1):

This bash script will move the files as named:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpg; do
   if [[ $f =~ ([^\)]+)\([^\)]+\)(.*) ]]; then
     mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}";
   fi
done
```

Original:

> ls [14]*
>   123-456(434).jpg  454-6hf(32).jpg

Post:

> ls [14]*
>   123-456.jpg  454-6hf.jpg

Note: if the files all definitely start with a number, you could adjust the `*.jpg` or the match to ensure limiting to just those files. The example above would, e.g., move `myfile(123).jpg` to `myfile.jpg`. Changing to `[0-9]*.jpg` would limit to just .jpg files that started with a number.